# XML and XSD mistake

Tags: xml, xsd

i need help to solve my error with this code of XML and XSD, please if u can check it and tell me a solution of why it doesn't works am gona be your slave
this is my XSD code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <xs:element name="clients">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="client" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="llinatge" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="edat" type="xs:decimal"/>
             <xs:element name="data_naixement" type="xs:date"/>
             <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="telefon" type="xs:decimal"/>
             </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="poblacio" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="codi" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
       </xs:complexType>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<clients
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="clients.xsd">

   <client codi="001">
   <llinatge>Alomar</llinatge>
   <edat>30</edat>
  <data_naixement poblacio="Palma de Mallorca">3-10-1989</data_naixement>
      <email>alomar@gmail.com</email>
  <telefon>600898989</telefon>


  </client>
   <client codi="002">
      <llinatge>Pérez</llinatge>
      <edat>47</edat>
      <data_naixement poblacio="Ciutadella">3-10-1975</data_naixement>
      <email>alomar@gmail.com</email>
  <telefon>600898989</telefon>
  
   </client>
</clients>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the XML shown and what you have attempted in your XSD, I would recommend something like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <xs:element name="clients">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="client" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="llinatge" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="edat" type="xs:decimal"/>
                            <xs:element name="data_naixement">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="poblacio" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="telefon" type="xs:decimal"/>
                        </xs:sequence>    
                        <xs:attribute name="codi" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that for the `data_naixement` I have it extending `xs:string` instead of `xs:date`, since those date values are not in the correct format YYYY-MM-DD. You could either assert some pattern restriction or correct the date format and change the type, depending upon what you are really expecting those values to be.

Comment: Thanks mate, i spend 1 week in that exercise, thank for help me